# Pandas find max value in one column and display from another row

Tags: python, pandas

Alabama 1   Byrne, Bradley  68.16   68.16   0.0
            LeFlore, Burton R.  31.71   31.71   0.0
            Unknown 0.13    0.13    0.0

I have a dataset that looks like such:

```
STATE | DISTRICT | CANDIDATE NAME | GENERAL VOTE
Alabama | 1 | Byrne, Bradley |  68.16
Alabama | 1 | LeFlore, Burton R. | 31.71
Alabama | 1 | Unknown | 0.13
Alabama | 2 | Name | 65.43
Alabama | 2 | Name | 0.13
```

I have to group by State and district because each state has multiple districts and there are many states. I have done this already.
However, I need to find the maximum of each grouping, and display the candidate name that coincides with this maximum. I also have to display the difference between the maximum and minimum general vote in each grouping. I have done some of this already but I am stuck

```
 df_out = dfworking.groupby(["STATE", "D", "CANDIDATE NAME"])['GENERAL PERCENT'].agg(['max','min'])
df_out['Margin'] = df_out['max']-df_out['min']
df_new_out = dfworking.groupby(['STATE','D'])['GENERAL PERCENT'].max()
```

I am not sure how to display the margin column, and the name that coincides with the maximum vote in the same dataframe.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Notice* - values in `STATE`, `DISTRICT` and `GENERAL VOTE` columns has to be sorted first.

```
#sorting
dfworking = dfworking.sort_values(['STATE','DISTRICT','GENERAL VOTE'], 
                                  ascending=[True, True, False])

#get index of max value in GENERAL VOTE column
df1 = dfworking.groupby(["STATE", "DISTRICT"])['GENERAL VOTE'].idxmax()
#create new column - not matched value return NaN
dfworking['cand'] = dfworking.loc[df1, 'CANDIDATE NAME']
#replace NaN by forward  filling
dfworking['cand'] = dfworking['cand'].ffill()

print (dfworking)
     STATE  DISTRICT      CANDIDATE NAME  GENERAL VOTE            cand
0  Alabama         1      Byrne, Bradley         68.16  Byrne, Bradley
1  Alabama         1  LeFlore, Burton R.         31.71  Byrne, Bradley
2  Alabama         1             Unknown          0.13  Byrne, Bradley
3  Alabama         2                Name         65.43            Name
4  Alabama         2                Name          0.13            Name
```

---

Another solution is create `df` with top candidate and [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original:

```
df1 = dfworking.loc[dfworking.groupby(["STATE", "DISTRICT"])['GENERAL VOTE'].idxmax()]
df1 = df1.set_index(['STATE','DISTRICT'])['CANDIDATE NAME'].rename('cand')
dfworking = dfworking.join(df1, on=['STATE','DISTRICT'])
print (dfworking)
     STATE  DISTRICT      CANDIDATE NAME  GENERAL VOTE            cand
0  Alabama         1      Byrne, Bradley         68.16  Byrne, Bradley
1  Alabama         1  LeFlore, Burton R.         31.71  Byrne, Bradley
2  Alabama         1             Unknown          0.13  Byrne, Bradley
3  Alabama         2                Name         65.43            Name
4  Alabama         2                Name          0.13            Name
```

Comment: Thank you, Just what I needed to get unstuck :)

Comment: Glad can help ;)